# Getting a tag as additional object returned in json while searching images by that tag

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Okay first of all I don't even know how to describe it in one sentence to ask google ( yes I did and I failed).

I have this gallery spring boot back-end application.
So there is Image class and Tag class between which is manytomany relationship.

Here are these classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Image {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "image_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;



@Column(name = "height")
private int height;

@Column(name = "width")
private int width;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(
        name="image_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="image_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
)
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
// getters / setters further
```

And this is my tag class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "tag_id")
private int id;

@Column(name ="name", length= 50)
private String name;

@Column(name = "createddate", length = 100)
private Date createdDate;



public Tag(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Tag() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Tag{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", createdDate=" + createdDate +
            '}';
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
private Set<Image> images = new HashSet<>();
```

This is how I get my Images by tag's name:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public List<Image> findByTag(String tag) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query<Image> query = session.createQuery("from Image as img inner join 
img.tags as tags where tags.name=:tagname");
    query.setParameter("tagname", tag);
    List<Image> images = query.getResultList();

    return images;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I make a get request with tag's name to get Images. Next to every Image object I receive there will also be that tag object with the name I used to look for images.

```
   {
        "@id": 2,
        "id": 6,
        "name": "peoples",
        "description": "some people hanging",
        "height": 501,
        "width": 780,
        "date": "2019-09-02T12:34:23.000+0000",
        "tags": [
           // there are more tags here I'm just saving space
            {   
                "id": 7,
                "name": "joy",
                "createdDate": "2019-09-03T12:27:49.000+0000",
                "images": [
                    2
                ]
            }
        ],
        "categories": [],
        "picture": " byte array of picture"
    },
```

Aand this is where magic happens, this object will be next to every Image object in Json response.

```
         {
         "id": 7,
         "name": "joy",
         "createdDate": "2019-09-03T12:27:49.000+0000",
         "images": [
             2
         ]
         }
```

I'm using Angular for front end and I can't fetch Images like this because I'll get an error because there will be tag object there.

Really hoping to figure this out!

```
@GetMapping("/tags/{tagname}")
public List<Image> getImageByTag(@PathVariable("tagname") String tagName){
    return imageService.findByTag(tagName);
}
```

And this is that service:

```
@Override
public List<Image> findByTag(String tag) {
    return imageDao.findByTag(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more like a json serialize problem. If you are using jackson as I guessed, you can try to manually control the output by following:

```
public class Image {
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

If you do need to include tag in some occasions, you might have to implement a JSON view

Comment: Tags from Image object are gone, but the additional ones are still there..

Comment: Could you also share your controller code? I don't find any place in your code would return any Tag object asides Image

Comment: The return type of the GET method in your controller is List<Image> , I don't see any possible way that Java will add Tag objects into the response body. Unfortunately I'm not able to help you figure it out.

Comment: Ah okay, there's something with @Jsonidentifyinfo annotation, but if I remove it my json many to many relationship wil loop infinitely

Comment: To solve the infinity loop problem, you can use combination of \@JsonManagedReference and \@JsonBackReference in your mapping

Comment: Apparently it was my bad with hibernate query. It returned both Image and tag and Java did let it to put result in Image List..